# How to update Django's template after backend change

Tags: python, django, templates, render

everyone. I'm starting with Python and Django and I want to add some Ajax to my code.

I'm practicing by showing a product on the template along with an input to change the price of it. 
I have been able to change his value on the DB but after that I'd like to update the template's context in order to see the new value. The field that I want to get updated is the last row of the table.

```
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Product</th>
  <td>{{product.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Price</th>
  <td><input id="price" type="text" value="{{product.price}}" placeholder="Price" autocomplete="off"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" style='background:none'><input id="send" type="button" value="Update"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Current values:</th>
  <td>{{product.name}} : ${{product.price}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The JS:

```
$("#send").click(function(){
  $.post("/inicio/acciones/update/", {search: 1, price : $("#price").val()} ).done(function(res){
})
```

});

Backend

```
def update(request):
  """backend changes
  ...
  """

  t = loader.get_template('inicio/index.html')
  product= Product.objects.get(pk=search)
  context = {
    'product' : product,
  }
  t.render(context)
  return HttpResponse(product.price)
```

The 'product' var has the right values but my template is not updated.

How can I update the context?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you clarify your question? If `product` has the attributes you want, what's stopping you from using them in your template?

Comment: Where is the rest of your Ajax `done` function?

Comment: Daniel, the done function doesn't do anything. I was hoping that the template could be updated by using only the update function.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris. Well, the template is already loaded and what I'm looking for is to send the product throughout the context. The template is first loaded with a product variable. Is that posible?

Comment: The page would be updated automatically *if you weren't using Ajax*. The whole point of using Ajax is to prevent precisely that, so that you can update things programatically in the JS itself. Since you don't want to do that, why exactly are you using Ajax? Just don't.

Comment: @DanielRoseman , I'm using AJAX because I wanted to send data without submitting a form and I thought Django could some way update the Context by itself without using the AJAX response. In the code I share there is no point of doing it but as I explained, it's kinda an example so in a more complex page the thing I'm proposing would be really useful but I think it's just not the way Django works.

Comment: It's not Django that doesn't work like that, but the web. If you want to send data by Ajax, you need to do something in your JS with the response. But I don't understand why you don't just wrap those input fields in a form.

Comment: I don’t do anything with the AJAX response because that wasn’t the point of my question. Otherwise I would have evaluated it and do something with it. But, again, that wasn’t the point. Anyway, I have my answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using AJAX, I am going to assume that whatever operation you are trying to conduct, you want to do it without reloading the entire page.

1. If this is the case...

   - Django templates aren't going to help you. At least, not in the way you think. 
     Django templates generate HTML based on the information given to them. It looks 
     like you are returning the desired queryset to the client in your AJAX response. 
     Someone correct me if i'm wrong but, Django is smart here and it's actually returning 
     your queryset as an already nicely formatted JSON response. Once your client has the 
     response, its up to the javascript running on the client to display the information 
     in the manner you desire. You would have to parse the JSON response and display the 
     information by manipulating page elements (probably using JQUERY since you seem to be using that already). Option #2 is instead of passing the filtered queryset directly back to the client, you could pass it to your template and have it generate some more HTML with a smaller subset of information. Then maybe you pass that back to the client. You would still have to wipe existing page elements and replace them with this new HTML using javascript though. As you can see this AJAX stuff gets pretty involved and you really only do it when it  doesn't make sense to reload the page.
2. If you meant to reload the entire page however...

   - This would be a good opportunity to start learning about Django forms. Not only would you be able to use your template in the way you want, form submission is a very important part of Django. Instead of your `#send` button running some AJAX request, you could make it the submit button of a form (GET request form). Submitting this form and pointing it to the same URL would load a new page. The catch here is that your form will also send some extra data along with the GET request that we can read in the view. Your view could then, upon recieving a GET request, attempt to read the contents of that request. If there is nothing, you could default to showing everything (I assume that's what you're doing now) if there is something in the request however, you could read it, and use that information to filter down the queryset you send to the template. You would end up using the same template, but it would show more or less information based on the queryset given to it by the view.

Comment: That explains quite well what my options are. Thank you so much. I will look into Django forms now.